# Min, max and average bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm making a chart with min, max and average values for a set of categories. My inspiration is Picture 2. With help from a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325599/min-max-and-average-in-bar-chart-pgfplots) asked, I've been able to make what's shown in Picture 1.

Is there a way to change the ends of the error bars into other shapes (square, circle), like the ones in Picture 2?

Is there a way to make add labels showing which values are max, min and average, like in Picture 2? ("Landsgjennomsnitt" = average, " ... høyest andel" = max, etc.)

Is there a way to add small text next to max and min value of each bar? As shown in Picture 3.

```
\pgfplotstableread{
x y y-max y-min
{Kategori 1} 9.2 7.3 5.3
{Kategori 2} 11.1 4.3 4.8
{Kategori 3} 12.2  3.5 3.3
{Kategori 4}  12.3  3.7 3.5
{Kategori 5}  21.0 5.2 3.7
}{\differanser}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3] 
\begin{axis} [
width  = 0.5*\textwidth,
height = 8cm,
symbolic x coords={{Kategori 1},{Kategori 2},{Kategori 3},{Kategori 4},{Kategori 5}},
minor ytick={5,10,15,20,25},
yminorgrids,
xtick=data,
ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}
]
\addplot+[blue, very thick, forget plot,only marks] 
plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-max}] {\differanser};
\addplot+[red, very thick, only marks,xticklabels=\empty] 
plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-min}] {\differanser};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to want also legend entries, the simplest option may be to add the corresponding plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x y y-max y-min
{Kategori 1} 9.2 7.3 5.3
{Kategori 2} 11.1 4.3 4.8
{Kategori 3} 12.2  3.5 3.3
{Kategori 4}  12.3  3.7 3.5
{Kategori 5}  21.0 5.2 3.7
}{\differanser}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3] 
\begin{axis} [
width  = 0.5*\textwidth,
height = 8cm,
symbolic x coords={{Kategori 1},{Kategori 2},{Kategori 3},{Kategori 4},{Kategori 5}},
minor ytick={5,10,15,20,25},
yminorgrids,
xtick=data,
ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
legend style={at={(0.05,0.95)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west},column
sep=1ex}
]
\addplot+[blue, very thick, forget plot,only marks,forget plot] 
plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-max}] {\differanser};
\addplot+[red, very thick, only marks,xticklabels=\empty,forget plot] 
plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-min}] {\differanser};
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark options={fill=blue,draw=red,very thick}] 
table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}] {\differanser};
\addlegendentry{average}
\addplot[only marks,mark=square*,color=blue] 
table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}+\thisrow{y-max}] {\differanser};
\addlegendentry{max}
\addplot[only marks,mark=square*,color=red] 
table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}-\thisrow{y-min}] {\differanser};
\addlegendentry{min}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]